# randcolor() function not randomizing - python

Tags: python-3.x, function, random

I have a little script that displays my MOTD upon shell login, which is an ASCII pic with text, in a color gradient using the **colr** library to create the gradient. I wrote a function to randomize a list of colors and when I run in IDLE it will pull a random color from the list. However when I run the script it only appears to return the first element (**red**). Here is my function:

```
from random import randint
from colr import Colr as C
def randcolor():
        colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'cyan', 'orange']
        n = (len(colors))
        o = randint(0, n-1)
        color = colors[o]
        return color
```

so when run in IDLE here are the results:

```
>>> randcolor()
'red'
>>> randcolor()
'red'
>>> randcolor()
'green'
>>> randcolor()
'cyan'
>>> randcolor()
'green'
>>> randcolor()
'red'
>>> randcolor()
'orange'
>>> randcolor()
'green'
```

But when I implement it in my script it appears to only return the first element:

```
f = open('/etc/motd', 'r')
    motd = f.readlines()
    f.close()

print(str(C(' '.join(motd)).gradient(name=randcolor()))
```

I can't add the results from the script here but suffice it to say that it is not changing the gradient. What is going wrong?

Also I was wondering if this could be done as a **lambda**. I tried to just assign a variable: `color = colors[(randint(0, len(colors)-1))]` but that only returned the first element as the script is doing. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `random.choice`?

Comment: Well I'm still learning and not all that familiar with the random library yet. I'll try that out and see if it corrects things.

Comment: Using `o` for a variable name will get you in trouble sooner or later. It looks too much like `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Steven for the **random.choice()** solution.

```
print(str(C(' '.join(motd)).gradient(name=random.choice(colors))))
```